# How do i create a rootCA for UWP apps in windows 10?

Tags: c#, win-universal-app

I am trying to create a root certificate authority for a UWP app, which allows the users to install a certificate before the app is intialized. the X509 certificates cannot be used here. Im trying to use the standard "Certificate" class inside the Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates namespace.Now after i create a certificate i am not able to add the certificate to a certificate store.Can someone help me with this?

this is my code

```
byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(path: @"C:\Users\Administrator\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\rootCA\rootCA\dig.crt");
String Cert = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
byte[] _buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Cert);
IBuffer _buffer1 = _buffer.AsBuffer();

//creating a certificate
Certificate file = new Certificate(_buffer1);
CertificateStore store = new CertificateStore();
```

The last line in the code throws me a constructor doesn't have arguments error.